# Winforms Animated background

Tags: c#, winforms

i want the background of my winform to be animated like a animated gif in the background or a video file being played as a background or a flash movie... how to do it

Answer (score -4, accepted):

move to WPF........

Answer (score 6):

Simply get a control that do this what you want (e.g. ImageBox) and set the Dock-Property to fill to complete Page. 
Than all other controls that you put in your form will be on this ImageBox.

Answer (score 5):

for a **.gif** use a PictureBox

for a **video** use WMP (windows media player .net component)

for a **flash** you could use the Shockwave Flash Object to display the content

EDIT: the WMP might not be in your toolbox by default, select it by right-clicking in the toolbox and click "Select items..."
this also counts for the Shockwave Flash Object

Comment: i want all this in the background.. like this should be in a layer and there shoild be a lyer above it containing all the UI componenets n all