# PictureBox in the Background?

Tags: winforms, powershell, background, gif

I want to display a GIF as background in my Form that I created with PowerShell.

I already figured out how to display the GIF and it works great, but of course all my Buttons and Textboxes etc. disappear behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Background images are assigned via the `BackgroundImage` property of the form:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form

$img = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\path\to\your.gif')
$form.BackgroundImage = $img
$form.BackgroundImageLayout = 'Tile'

$form.ShowDialog()
```

See [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stephap/archive/2012/04/23/building-forms-with-powershell-part-1-the-form.aspx) for more information about using forms in PowerShell.

For displaying an *animated* GIF (you should've mentioned that in your question) it seems a `PictureBox` element is [required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1819018/1630171). You can get it behind other elements by adding it after other elements (new elements are placed behind/below existing elements):

```
$img = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\path\to\your.gif')

$picbox = New-Object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$picbox.Width  = $img.Size.Width
$picbox.Height = $img.Size.Height
$picbox.Image  = $img

$form.Controls.Add($otherElement)
$form.Controls.Add($yetAnotherElement)
$form.Controls.Add($picbox)
```

or by sending it to the back via the [`SendToBack()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback.aspx) method:

```
$img = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\path\to\your.gif')

$picbox = New-Object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$picbox.Width  = $img.Size.Width
$picbox.Height = $img.Size.Height
$picbox.Image  = $img

$form.Controls.Add($picbox)
$form.Controls.Add($otherElement)
$form.Controls.Add($yetAnotherElement)

$picbox.SendToBack()
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked out, but the Gif is not moving anymore, do you have a solution for this? I would be very thankful.